# How to specify more than one artifact pattern for a resolver in ivy?

Tags: ant, ivy

I am using ivy with ant to build multiple modules. When I use a resolver to publish, can I specify more than one artifact pattern based on the artifact type? I see resolver, in my case filesystem resolver, allows multiple artifact elements inside it. Can I use this for my purpose. If so, how? I tried adding type or ext attribute on the artifact, inside filesystem resolver and it is throwing exceptions :

```
no set method found for type on class org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvyPattern
```

and

```
no set method found for ext on class org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvyPattern
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the artefact pattern during publish

```
<target name="publish" depends="jar, test" unless="option.noresolve" description="Publish produced artifacts in Ivy repository">
    <ivy:publish pubrevision="${publish.version}" artifactspattern="${jars}/[artifact].[ext]" status="${publish.status}" resolver="local" forcedeliver="true" update="true" overwrite="true"/>
</target>
```

${jars} it's just a path to output jars.

In ivy.xml you describe your publications like this:

```
<publications>
    <artifact name="strongpoint" ext="jar" type="jar"/>
</publications>
```

Comment: Isn't artifactspattern sepecify pattern to find the artifacts for publishing? Does it tell where the found artifacts to be published at the destination? I have a module folder, under it I have Build, src & doc folders. I want to publish the jar from build folder and documents from doc folder. In my Ivysettings file have < property name="ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/ >. So, when I publish documents they are being placed each under different folder. I want to publish docs to 'doc' folder, how can I do that?

Comment: I am using ivy.share.default.artifact.pattern in filesystem resolver as artifact pattern. I am confused so the pattern I specify on the artifact tag, does this specify where to find the artifacts for publishing using this resolver? That means the same pattern should be used to publish them too, right? So, is artifactspattern attribute on the publish task specify where to find the artfacts that need to be published to this (in my cased shared resolver) resolver? Please clarify if my understanding is right?